# ruby regex scan and gsub work differently with capture groups in blocks

Tags: ruby, regex, capture-group

I have a string of alternating digits and letters. I want to replace each character with the number of letters preceding it. For example, `2a3b` should return `aabbb`.

First, If I do:

```
"2a3b".scan(/(\d)(.)/) do |count, char|
  puts char * count.to_i
end
```

I get:

```
aa
bbb
```

But, if I do:

```
"2a3b".gsub(/(\d)(.)/) do |count, char|
  char * count.to_i
end
```

I get an error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `*' for nil:NilClass
```

Shouldn't they both behave the same (Update: I mean, accept capture groups as block params)?

**Update** : (workaround, which works)

```
"2a3b".gsub(/(\d)(.)/) do |match|
  $2 * $1.to_i
end
```

returns:

```
"aabbb"
```

as expected.

Comment: I really like both of your approaches here. However I feel the 'update' is unnecessary and also dilutes the answers below, so best to revert back to the original question.

Comment: @sagarpandya82 the first update clarifies my intent, since one response completely misinterpreted my question. The second update was made before the first answer came about, will expand a bit on that to clarify.

Comment: This [link](http://batsov.com/articles/2013/08/30/using-gsub-with-a-block/)  says it well - *some people expect that gsub would yield to the block all the matched groups as arguments – that is not the case, you’ll always get a single argument denoting the entire regexp match.*

Comment: I agree with @sagarpandya82. Questions are not intended to contain answers. You may of course post an answer to your own question or post a comment on an answer that suggests how it could be improved.

Comment: @CarySwoveland - I mentioned it as a workaround, not an answer - and still see it as that - I would like a way to get at the capture groups as block arguments (like scan provides), if I can - but it turns out that the workaround is the best thing available right now, hence I accepted the answer that gave evidence for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No they don't behave the same.
The block form of gsub only accepts one parameter, so the second is going to be nil, hence your error.
See http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-gsub

Example of use: `"hello".gsub(/./) {|s| s.ord.to_s + ' '}`

> In the block form, the current match string is passed in as a
>   parameter, and variables such as $1, $2, $`, $&, and $' will be set
>   appropriately. The value returned by the block will be substituted for
>   the match on each call.
>
> The result inherits any tainting in the original string or any
>   supplied replacement string.

Comment: Yeah, I edited the original question with a workaround. I guess the best option is to use the match in the block.

Answer (score 0):

No, they are two different methods and do different things.

See http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#gsub-method and http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#scan-method

In the abstract, scan is more for finding patterns in strings/expressions, (and with a block, formatting them in some way) while gsub is more about doing replacements on patterns in a string.